# scrape sports reference table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have tried the following script to make to grab the table on the webpage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/play-index/rivals.cgi?request=1&school_id=penn-state&opp_id=purdue'

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

pageTree = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

soup.find('tbody')
```

However, the table is not able to be pulled. Not even a "pd.read_html" line works. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

The desired table data is under html comment. By removing the comment,you can extract the table data using pandas only.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/play-index/rivals.cgi?request=1&school_id=penn-state&opp_id=purdue'
res = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')

soup =BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')

table = soup.select_one('#div_results')

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
d = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
 G        Date  Day           School Unnamed: 4_level_1     Opponent  ... Diff   W  L  T  Streak  Notes
0   19  2019-10-05  Sat  Penn State (12)                NaN       Purdue  ...   28  15  3  1     W 9    NaN
1   18  2016-10-29  Sat  Penn State (24)                  @       Purdue  ...   38  14  3  1     W 8    NaN
2   17  2013-11-16  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  ...   24  13  3  1     W 7    NaN
3   16  2012-11-03  Sat       Penn State                  @       Purdue  ...   25  12  3  1     W 6    NaN
4   15  2011-10-15  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  ...    5  11  3  1     W 5    NaN
5   14  2008-10-04  Sat   Penn State (6)                  @       Purdue  ...   14  10  3  1     W 4    NaN
6   13  2007-11-03  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  ...    7   9  3  1     W 3    NaN
7   12  2006-10-28  Sat       Penn State                  @       Purdue  ...   12   8  3  1     W 2    NaN
8   11  2005-10-29  Sat  Penn State (11)                NaN       Purdue  ...   18   7  3  1     W 1    NaN
9   10  2004-10-09  Sat       Penn State                NaN   Purdue (9)  ...   -7   6  3  1     L 2    NaN
10   9  2003-10-11  Sat       Penn State                  @  Purdue (18)  ...  -14   6  2  1     L 1    NaN
11   8  2000-09-30  Sat       Penn State                NaN  Purdue (22)  ...    2   6  1  1     W 6    NaN
12   7  1999-10-23  Sat   Penn State (2)                  @  Purdue (16)  ...    6   5  1  1     W 5    NaN
13   6  1998-10-17  Sat  Penn State (12)                NaN       Purdue  ...   18   4  1  1     W 4    NaN
14   5  1997-11-15  Sat   Penn State (6)                  @  Purdue (19)  ...   25   3  1  1     W 3    NaN
15   4  1996-10-12  Sat  Penn State (10)                NaN       Purdue  ...   17   2  1  1     W 2    NaN
16   3  1995-10-14  Sat  Penn State (20)                  @       Purdue  ...    3   1  1  1     W 1    NaN
17   2  1952-09-27  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  ...    0   0  1  1     T 1    NaN
18   1  1951-11-03  Sat       Penn State                  @       Purdue  ...  -28   0  1  0     L 1    NaN

[19 rows x 16 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<table>` is stored inside HTML comment `<!-- -->` so `beautifulsoup` normally doesn't see it. To parse it you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/play-index/rivals.cgi?request=1&school_id=penn-state&opp_id=purdue"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
}

pageTree = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, "html.parser")

df = pd.read_html("\n".join(soup.find_all(text=Comment)))[0]
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     G        Date  Day           School Unnamed: 4_level_1     Opponent     Conf Unnamed: 7_level_1  Pts  Opp  Diff   W  L  T Streak  Notes
0   19  2019-10-05  Sat  Penn State (12)                NaN       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   35    7    28  15  3  1    W 9    NaN
1   18  2016-10-29  Sat  Penn State (24)                  @       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   62   24    38  14  3  1    W 8    NaN
2   17  2013-11-16  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   45   21    24  13  3  1    W 7    NaN
3   16  2012-11-03  Sat       Penn State                  @       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   34    9    25  12  3  1    W 6    NaN
4   15  2011-10-15  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   23   18     5  11  3  1    W 5    NaN
5   14  2008-10-04  Sat   Penn State (6)                  @       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   20    6    14  10  3  1    W 4    NaN
6   13  2007-11-03  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   26   19     7   9  3  1    W 3    NaN
7   12  2006-10-28  Sat       Penn State                  @       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   12    0    12   8  3  1    W 2    NaN
8   11  2005-10-29  Sat  Penn State (11)                NaN       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   33   15    18   7  3  1    W 1    NaN
9   10  2004-10-09  Sat       Penn State                NaN   Purdue (9)  Big Ten                  L   13   20    -7   6  3  1    L 2    NaN
10   9  2003-10-11  Sat       Penn State                  @  Purdue (18)  Big Ten                  L   14   28   -14   6  2  1    L 1    NaN
11   8  2000-09-30  Sat       Penn State                NaN  Purdue (22)  Big Ten                  W   22   20     2   6  1  1    W 6    NaN
12   7  1999-10-23  Sat   Penn State (2)                  @  Purdue (16)  Big Ten                  W   31   25     6   5  1  1    W 5    NaN
13   6  1998-10-17  Sat  Penn State (12)                NaN       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   31   13    18   4  1  1    W 4    NaN
14   5  1997-11-15  Sat   Penn State (6)                  @  Purdue (19)  Big Ten                  W   42   17    25   3  1  1    W 3    NaN
15   4  1996-10-12  Sat  Penn State (10)                NaN       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   31   14    17   2  1  1    W 2    NaN
16   3  1995-10-14  Sat  Penn State (20)                  @       Purdue  Big Ten                  W   26   23     3   1  1  1    W 1    NaN
17   2  1952-09-27  Sat       Penn State                NaN       Purdue  Western                  T   20   20     0   0  1  1    T 1    NaN
18   1  1951-11-03  Sat       Penn State                  @       Purdue  Western                  L    0   28   -28   0  1  0    L 1    NaN
```